# Using ScriptCombining through a ScriptManager on a Master Page

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 adds a great new ScriptCombining feature to the ScriptManager object as demonstrated on [this video](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-296.aspx?wwwaspnetrdirset=1). However he only demonstrates how to use the feature with the ScriptManager on the same page. I'd like to use this feature on a site where the scriptmanager is on the master page but can't figure out how to add the scripts I need for each page programmatically to the manager. I've found [this post](http://seejoelprogram.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/net-35-sp1-doesnt-provide-composite-script-registration-from-an-iscriptcontrol-out-of-the-box/) to use as a starting point, but I'm not really getting very far. can anyone give me a helping hand?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
    ScriptReference SRef = new ScriptReference();
    SRef.Path = "~/Scripts/Script.js";


    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).CompositeScript.Scripts.Add(SRef);
```

That will get the current scriptmanager (even if it is on a master page) and add a script reference to the CompositeScript properties.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot when I get in tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in markup using [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx).

You can add the ScriptManager to the master page e.g.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server">
    <CompositeScript>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference name="WebForms.js" assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjax.js" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <asp:ScriptReference name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </Scripts>
    </CompositeScript>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And then add the ScriptManagerProxy to the content page e.g.

```
<asp:Content ID="HomeContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolder" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server">
        <CompositeScript>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/yourscript.js" />
        </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```